# Is there a way to have onenote 2013 update or refresh the contents of an HTML page when the HTML page changes (i.e Wiki, Blogs, etc.,)?

Tags: web, ms-office, onenote

I can copy contents from any website but it will only take the current contents.  I would like to be able to have the information in onenote change or refresh (automatically or by selecting an option) when there is a change or update in a blog or wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are an end user question about OneNote and not a developer question? Anyhow, dynamic HTML content is not supported by OneNote apps today. You can go vote for this idea on the official OneNote feedback forum here: http://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/256328-onenote-users/suggestions/5776804-embed-video-webpages-and-other-live-content-in-o

-- James